# What are the scopes to select in mapbox token access geocoding?

Tags: wordpress, api, mapbox, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using WordPress to build my website. As part of the custom theme, I can choose Mapbox API for my location based search results. However, I am not entirely sure what "scope" to select when creating a token access. Attached is the screenshot. I am looking for the Mapbox [Geocoding](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/) feature.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

All tokens are able to geocode locations, so you do not need to set a particular [scope](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/access-tokens/#access-token-scopes) to use the [Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/geocoding/).

Disclaimer - I work at Mapbox.

Comment: Hi Patrick, I'm also trying to use geocoding but it keeps returning a list of empty features, what could be the problem here?

Comment: @DomyKanyik-tesh - could you ask this in a new post with replication details?

Comment: @PatrickLeonard does this mean that even *public* tokens can be used for geocoding?

Comment: @jareks yes, that is correct: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/getting-started/access-tokens/

Comment: @PatrickLeonard it sounds like anyone can copy public token from a website and use it to send geocoding requests from his/her server at expense of victim. Am I missing something?